# Show that $B$ is invertible if $B=A^2-2A+2I$ and $A^3=2I$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is $40\times 40$ matrix such that $A^3=2I$ show that $B$ is invertible where $B=A^2-2A+2I$.

I tried to evaluate $B(A-I)$ , $B(A+I)$ , $B(A-2I)$ ...  but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 14):

You can find the inverse directly by solving 
$$\left(\alpha A^2+\beta A +\gamma I\right)B=I.$$
If you do, you will find that $\alpha = 1/10$, $\beta = 3/10$, and $\gamma = 4/10$. Hence, $$B^{-1} = \tfrac{1}{10}A^2+\tfrac{3}{10}A+\tfrac{4}{10}I.$$
This can be easily checked by multiplying out and using the relation $A^{3}=2I$.

Comment: This method is really good ...but it looks kind of *circular* to me as the question was asking to **prove** that $B$ is invertible ...so doesn't that mean we have to somehow find another matrix say $Q$ such that $BQ=I$ but you have just *assumed* in the *first step itself* that $B$ is an invertible matrix so that $B^{-1}B=I$ ...sure you have indeed said in the end we can cross-check it by multiplying out...but is this method correct mathematically speaking ??

Comment: Because the *Question* was to prove $B$ is invertible and you first used $BB^{-1}=I$ which is applicable when $B$ was invertible and then you say we have found the value of $B^{-1}$ and we have also checked it ...thus $B$ must be invertible ....but you had assumed this(*that $B$ is invertible*) right from the start !!! Otherwise one couldn't have said that $B^{-1}B=I$ or $$\left(\alpha A^2+\beta A +\gamma I\right)B=I$$

Comment: Hi Freelancer. There is no guarantee that my initial equation will have a solution. If it did not, then we would have wasted some time. But if it does have a solution, then the matrix that is found (call it $Q$) is the inverse because it has the required property that $QB=I$.

Answer (score 14):

Here's something I call the "**miracle method**" for this type of problem. Suspend your disbelief for a moment and suppose $A$ and $B$ were scalars, not matrices. Then, we would simply be looking for
$$ \frac{1}{B} = \frac{1}{A^2 - 2A - 2} = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{A}{2}+\frac{A^2}{4}-\frac{A^4}{8}-\frac{A^5}{8} + \cdots$$
where in the power series expansion, the coefficient of $A^n$ is
$$ c_n = \frac{1+i}{2^{n+2}} \left((1-i)^n-i (1+i)^n\right). $$
But we know that $A^3 = 2$, so this becomes
$$ \frac{1}{2}+\frac{A}{2}+\frac{A^2}{4}-\frac{A^4}{8}-\frac{A^5}{8} + \cdots = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{A}{2}+\frac{A^2}{4}-\frac{A}{4}-\frac{A^2}{4} + \cdots $$
and by summing the resulting coefficients on $1$, $A$, and $A^2$, we find that
$$ \frac{1}{B} = \frac{2}{5} + \frac{3}{10}A + \frac{1}{10}A^2. $$
Now, what we've just done should be total nonsense if $A$ and $B$ are really matrices, not scalars. But try setting $B^{-1} = \frac{2}{5}I + \frac{3}{10}A + \frac{1}{10}A^2$, and you'll find that, **miraculously**, this answer works!

Comment: What the hell hahaha, why does this work? I'm astounded!

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD To be honest, I'm really not sure! I discovered this technique some time ago by accident, and it seems to produce meaningful answers for problems of this type. [I've asked another question here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1399754/80762) if anyone has ideas as to why this works.

Answer (score 11):

The eigenvalues of $A$ are the cubic roots of $2$. Then
$$B=(A-(1+i)I)(A-(1-i)I)$$
is a regular matrix.

Answer (score 7):

You have
$$B=A^3+A^2-2A=A(A-I)(A+2I)\ .$$
$A$ is invertible, and since
$$A^3-I=I\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad(A-I)(A^2+A+I)=I$$
and 
$$A^3+8I=10I\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad(A+2I)(A^2-2A+4I)=10I$$
also $(A-I)$ and $(A+2I)$ are invertible.

Now, since $B$ is the product of invertible matrices, it is invertible.

Comment: I think it is correct: $B=A^2-2A+2I$ and $2I=A^3$

Comment: Ohh......!!!!!.

Answer (score 5):

One of the easiest ways to prove $B$ is invertible is the following;
$$B=A^2-2A+2I$$
Using that $A^3=2I$, we can write 
$$B=A^2-2A+2I= A^2-2A + A^3 = A(A^2+A-2I)=A(A+2I)(A-I)$$
Now let us prove $A$, $A+2I$ and $A-I$ are invertible.

1. Supose there is $v$ such that $Av=0$, then we have $0=A^20=A^3v=2Iv=2v$. So we have $v=0$. So $A$ is invertible.
2. Supose there is $v$ such that $(A+2I)v=0$, then we have $Av=-2v$ and we have $A^3v=-8v$. So we get $-8v=A^3v=2Iv=2v$. So we have $v=0$. So $(A+2I)$ is invertible.
3. Supose there is $v$ such that $(A-I)v=0$, then we have $Av=v$ and we have $A^3v=v$. So we get $v=A^3v=2Iv=2v$. So we have $v=0$. So $(A-I)$ is invertible.

Since B is the product of three invertible matrices, B itself is invertible.

**Remark**: For item 1 above, we also simply present the inverse of $A$. From $A^3=2I$, we have $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}A^2$.

Comment: Nice. Best solution.

Answer (score 3):

A few manipulations:

$$B=A^2-2A+2I$$
$$A^3 = 2I$$

then,

$$AB = A^3 -2A^2+2A \\= 2I -2A^2+2A \\= -2(A^2-2A+2I)-2A+6I \\= -2B -2A+6I$$

Now, the fact that $A^3 = 2I$ means $A$ is invertible, because $\det(A) \neq 0$

Thus,

$$B = -2A^{-1}B-2I+6A^{-1} $$

Take $B$ to one side:

$$B(I+2A^{-1}) = -2I+6A^{-1}$$
Multiply both side with $A$:
$$B(A+2I) = -2A+6I$$

I suppose those quantities will be similar.

Answer (score 3):

$B=(A-I)^2+I$. Now claim that $1\pm i$ are NOT  eigen values of $A$. Otherwise , $(1\pm i)^3$ are eigen values of $A^3$ , which is NOT possible. So , $\pm i$ are NOT eigen values of $A-I$. Then , $(\pm i)^2=-1$ is NOT an eigen value of $(A-I)^2$  .

Then $0$ is NOT an eigen value of $(A-I)^2+I$  and consequently $B$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $B$ is invertible if and only if $0$ is *not* and eigenvalue of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

$B=A^2-2A+2I$. Now multiplying the sides respectively by $A$ and $A^2$, and using the assumption $A^3=2I$ yields:
                             $$AB=BA=-2A^2+2A+2I$$
                             $$A^2B=BA^2=2A^2+2A-4I$$
Therefore
                             $$AB+A^2B=4A-2I$$
                             $$AB+2B=-2A+6I$$
By straightforward algebraic manipulation, it comes that:
                             $$A^2B+3AB+4B=BA^2+3BA+4B=10I$$
                             $$(A^2+3A+4I)B=B(A^2+3A+4I)=10I$$
Therefore
                             $$B^{-1}=(A^2+3A+4I)/10$$