# Prove that $B = A^2 - 2A + 2I$ is an invertible matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

> If $A$ is a matrix such that $A^3 = 2I$, prove that $B = A^2 - 2A + 2I$ is an invertible matrix.

---

I tried to use $A^3 = 2I$ and turn it to $(A-I)(A^2 + A + I) = I$ but it didn't work. also I tried to suppose $B$ has inverse and solve the problem but it didn't work either.

Comment: What have you tried so far

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I tried to use $A^3$ = 2I and turn it to (A-I)($A^2$ + A + I) = I
but it didn't work.
also I tried to suppose B has inverte and solve the problem but it didn't work too.

Comment: @FATEMEHMOUSAVI Are you allowed to use diagonalization ?

Comment: Yes, I think ..

Comment: @FATEMEHMOUSAVI I will write an answer whether the question reopens.

Comment: Take a look at the question [Show that $B$ is invertible if $B=A^2-2A+2I$ and $A^3=2I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1378132/show-that-b-is-invertible-if-b-a2-2a2i-and-a3-2i). I like the miracle method usage, and the dimension condition isn't used in any of the answers.

Comment: The systematic way is to compute polynomial gcd: see  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=simplify+PolynomialExtendedGCD%5Bx%5E2-2x%2B2%2Cx%5E3-2%2Cx%5D